# Find constant-coefficient linear differential equation of the smallest possible order for $y(x) = x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find a constant-coefficient linear differential equation of the smallest possible order that has $y(x) = x^3$ as a solution.

My interpretation of the question is we are given the general solution, and now I have to find the differential equation that it's the solution to. A hint I'm given is "What are the characteristic roots associated with each function?"

I am not really sure what I am doing, but I figure a good direction to start is differentiating $y(x)$ so I do that and get

$$y' = 3x^2, y'' = 6x, y''' = 6 $$
and $$a_0x^3 + 3a_1x^2 + 6a_2x + 6a_3 = 0 $$

I also observe that the characteristic equation appears to have complex roots. $$r = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{6^2 - 72}}{6} = \frac{1}{2} \pm i$$

I think this is the right direction, but not sure. Any additional guidance on how to answer the question would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Doesn’t $y’=3x^2$ fit the bill?

Comment: Oh....damn you're right. I guess I overthought the problem really badly. How would the hint apply to this problem then?

Comment: I suppose the characteristic root is $0$

Comment: Your question did not say "homogeneous"?????  In that case order $1$ will do, $y'=3x^2$.  Or order $0$ even, $y=x^3$.

Comment: The book doesn't specify, but since we are in the homogeneous equations section, I guess it is homogeneous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y^{\prime\prime\prime\prime}=0$ is a linear homogenous differential equation with constant coefficients which has $x^3$ as a solution.

Let's try a smaller order: suppose $ay^{\prime\prime\prime}+by^{\prime\prime}+cy^{\prime}+dy=0$ is satisfied if $y=x^3$. We would have:

$$6a+6bx+3cx^2+dx^3=0$$

which would immediately imply $a=b=c=d=0$.

Comment: does this imply that $6a6 + 6bx + 3cx^2 + dx^3 = 0$ is what the problem is looking for?

Comment: @EvanKim No, the problem is looking for the equation $y^{\prime\prime\prime\prime}=0$. I mean ... let's read the problem: "Find a constant coefficient linear differential equation...".